# How to make new sheet in google spreadsheet selected?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script adds new sheet on a spreadsheet after some form submission. This sheet is used as a leaderboard. But to look on it I have to click on the new created tab. Is it any way to do it from script?

[image]

This picture is a screenshot after new sheet creation (Week 1 Lesson 2).

P.S.
I found that I have to reformulate the question. The problem is that I want to do it from another spreadsheet (this spreadsheet has onSubmit trigger and create and place info on other open spreadsheet (leaderboard). I check the setActiveSheet(sheet). It works only with the spreadsheet that runs the script. So I have to send some signal to leaderboard to activate sheet. But I can't understand how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the developers guide

```
setActiveSheet(sheet)
```

Comment: Thank you! I found that I have to reformulate the question. The problem is that I want to do it from another spreadsheet (this spreadsheet has onSubmit trigger and placed info on other open spreadsheet (leaderboard). I check the setActiveSheet(sheet). It works only with the spreadsheet that runs the script. So I have to send some signal to leaderboard to activate sheet. But I can't understand how to do that

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to use Apps Script to change the active sheet on another open spreadsheet not running the script.

You could install a time-based trigger that ran every minute in the leaderboard sheet that checked for a new entry and then changed the active sheet as needed. This isn't instant but would take at most 60 seconds to update.

Comment: Note that time based triggers are not generally bound to any given UI instance - in other words, you cannot use UI functionality in time based triggers. Have you checked if the same is true for your proposed solution?